# How to use ffmpeg to extract the third data stream in mpegts

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video

I've add a private text stream into the `mpegts`, as the third stream. Now I need get the stream payload with ffmpeg, I failed neither in command nor in code.

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'input.ts':
  Duration: 00:03:28.78, start: 81831.351800, bitrate: 1115 kb/s
  Program 1
  Stream #0:0[0x1000]: Video: hevc ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), none, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
  Stream #0:1[0x1001]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), mono, fltp, 71 kb/s
  Stream #0:2[0x1002]: Unknown: none ([128][0][0][0] / 0x0080)
```

Is it possible, that I modify the code in `mpegts.c`, to handle the `Stream #0:2`?
or just simply with a ffmpeg command?

Comment: Please share your command instead of writing "I failed in command nor in code" next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract it with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:2 -c copy -f data stream_data.txt
```

The resulting data will be output to `stream_data.txt`.

The `-f data` option instructs FFmpeg to just dump any binary/text data in the stream without performing any extra processes like it would normally do with an audio/video stream.

Comment: It says:
Input #0, mpegts, from 'input.ts':
  Duration: 00:03:28.78, start: 81831.351800, bitrate: 1115 kb/s
  Program 1
  Stream #0:0[0x1000]: Video: hevc ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), none, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
  Stream #0:1[0x1001]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), mono, fltp, 71 kb/s
  Stream #0:2[0x1002]: Unknown: none ([128][0][0][0] / 0x0080)
Cannot map stream #0:2 - unsupported type.
If you want unsupported types ignored instead of failing, please use the -ignore_unknown option
If you want them copied, please use -copy_unknown

Comment: I add -ignore_unknown, It says:
Input #0, mpegts, from 'input.ts':
  Duration: 00:03:28.78, start: 81831.351800, bitrate: 1115 kb/s
  Program 1
  Stream #0:0[0x1000]: Video: hevc ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), none, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
  Stream #0:1[0x1001]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), mono, fltp, 71 kb/s
  Stream #0:2[0x1002]: Unknown: none ([128][0][0][0] / 0x0080)
Cannot map stream #0:2 - unsupported type.
Output #0, data, to 'stream_data.txt':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Comment: Try adding `-copy_unknown` after `-c copy` (*without* the `-ignore_unknown` option) then, as the warning suggests. `-ignore_unknown` will obviously not output anything because the text stream is unsupported.